# Socket connection not happening between computers present on two separate LAN networks

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am trying to make a socket connection between two computers present on two separate LAN networks respectively. So this is how my two computers are set up. My MacBook is on a network where the router's IP is `121.245.152.106`. And my Dell PC is present on a network where the router's IP is `27.4.193.156`.

I am using my MacBook as my server. This code will just accept a socket connection from the client(Dell PC) and will print it's IP address. This code is present on my MacBook:

## LolServer.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;



public class LolServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080); // ServerSocket listening to port 8080 
        Socket socket = server.accept();
       
        System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()); // Printing the client IP address.  
       
        socket.close();
        server.close();
    }
}
```

When I

```
telnet 192.168.1.102 8080 
// or 
telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
```

from my local machine(MacBook), the code works fine and the `LolServer` program prints

```
192.168.1.102
// or 
127.0.0.1
```

respectively as its output. Here, `192.168.1.102` is the local/private IP address of my MacBook provided by the router with IP `121.245.152.106`.

Now here lies the problem. When I try to access the program from a remote network, i.e. from my Dell PC, the `telnet` command keeps searching for the server and doesn't print any output.

This is what I tried from the client side:

```
telnet 121.245.152.106 8080
```

this gives no output. It doesn't even print any output on my Macbook. I suppose my sockets were not even connected. Is `121.245.152.106` the IP to be used for the connection from my Dell PC? It makes no sense to do this:

```
telnet 192.168.1.102 8080
```

as `192.168.1.102` is the private IP address.

Please help me, I really need to get this working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not going to pretend I know too much here, but maybe you need to port forward? It doesn't seem like a problem with you code so my best guess would be firewall/port forward needed.

Comment: you need to give, live IP. and need to port forward as well

Comment: Yes. The IP is live. And how am I gonna do a port forwarding? I am still a student.

Comment: you need to configure this thing  in your router

Comment: Lookup NAT/DNAT. You'll need to forward port 8080 from the WAN side (public IP) to the LAN side (192.168.x.x) on your router(s)

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup, can you please tell me how am I gonna port forward from WAN side? I have never done that before.

Comment: There are plenty of resources on that, you should read before asking for help here. The exact procedure depends on your router; you might investigate uPNP also.

Answer (score 1):

> Port forwarding, sometimes referred to as port triggering, is a process of configuring a router to make a computer or network device that is connected to it accessible to other computers and network devices from outside of the local network.

Source: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-K6jMYBfuIY

This means that the connection is being block by your router. Also port forwarding for the first time is tricky and somewhat beyond my abilities to instruct. Here is a good website to help you: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/ basically you select your router and the site will teach you based on your router.

Comment: Cant I do it without having access to the routers? I mean, apps like skype, ms outlook, etc do communicate with their servers. Cant I do something like that?

Comment: you need to have access to your router. I don't think so, there is anyother way out unless i'm mistaken.

Comment: Well that could be a problem. I guess log me in hamachi *could* work but I wouldn't be too keen on that approach.

Comment: Actually in this scenario, my client PC knows the dynamic IP of my server PC(actually my friend was sitting on the MacBook).  But apps like skype do communicate with their servers. They don't need any port forwarding. Or do they?

Comment: Log me in uses network tunneling to talk to other clients. Raw sockets won't get through if they are not forwarded. Skype uses a technique called hole punching. Google it under "hole punching firewall".